# "approach to provide" or "approach to providing"

Tags: grammar, verbs, infinitives, ing

1. An energy-efficient approach to **provide** an optimal solution to this problem.
2. An energy-efficient approach to **providing** an optimal solution to this problem.

Comment: An energy-efficient version would say:  *An energy-efficient solution to this problem.*

Answer (score 1):

1 is correct without change. 2 would be correct if you remove the 'to' before 'providing'.

**EDIT: Rewrite for clarity**
If I understand the meaning you are attempting to convey, 1 is correct without change as this gives the feeling of finality i.e. this is the chosen/best option. 2 would be similar if you removed the 'to' before 'providing' as this would also give a sense of finality i.e. this will be the chosen/best option. 2 without change could be used, but would be better suited to a pitch, as is does not feel as final i.e. this could be a good choice and should be considered.

If you are just asking because you have seen both and are wondering if one is wrong, then no, they are both correct grammatically. My answer would only stand if you are trying to convey a specific type of message with the sentence.

Comment: 2 is grammatical as it is too.

Comment: That is true, but it feels like it changes the meaning to me.

Comment: It *is* grammatical -- it had me fooled for a minute.  It's hard to explain what the difference is, but they mean something different.  If you say "We need an energy-efficient approach *to provide* an optimal solution to this problem," you're saying that the energy-efficient approach will *be* the solution to the problem.  If you say "We need an energy-efficient approach providing an optimal solution to this problem." you mean the energy-efficient approach will help to find the solution.  I'm not even sure I'm saying that right -- maybe someone with more working brain cells can help.

Comment: @Ajaypayne All three versions mean slightly different things.

Comment: They do, but 'to provide' and 'providing' both carry a sense of finality: to provide = will provide, providing = is providing, whereas 'to providing' feels more like an option that could be chosen. While you are correct in the fact that they are both grammatical, which is what the question asked (which makes my answer wrong I admit) without knowing what the approach is, what the solution is for, or if this is a pitch or a report, I stand by my answer for my understanding of the context of the phrased question.

Comment: My brain cells say, forget the subtle nuances, and go with Tim Romano "answer" in the first comment, above.  If you want to make sure the reader gets a subtle nuance (whatever it is in this case), you will have to explain it, which rather defeats the purpose of being subtle.

Comment: His answer says that the solution is energy efficient, the OP is saying that the approach is energy efficient. His answer changes the context, my answer clarifies the meaning without changing the context. If it makes you feel better, I can certainly change my answer to give a more in depth explanation? If it makes it easier for your brain cells to comprehend it...

Comment: My brain cells will thank you if you do.  Also, Answers, as opposed to comments, are supposed to have either references or convincing explanations to back them up.

Comment: Done, and FYI, I was starting to get a bit aggravated with this exchange, but your last comment really placated me somehow and I really feel the need to apologise for being snarky. I don't know how you managed to make that happen but you definitely have a skill there.

Comment: +1 for a thoughtful answer with the logic explained.  (And the graceful apology did not influence the upvote, which was strictly on merit)

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence elides the sense of *in order* before *to provide*. The second addresses the *provision* of solutions. They are not equivalent, but neither is incorrect. In the second sentence, removing the *to*, which acts as a preposition here and not as a particle of the infinitive like it does above, brings their meanings closer, and conveys the sense of *that provides/will provide*.